# Image is broken when downloaded from Facebook using cURL in PHP

Tags: php, facebook, curl

Here's the script I use to download an image from Facebook

```
function downloadImage($image_url)
{
  // Set filename
  $filename = dirname(__FILE__).'/wow.jpg';
  // Proceed to download
  // Open file to save
  $file = fopen($filename, 'w');
  // Use curl
  $ch = curl_init($image_url);
  // Set options
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, ''); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0'); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); 
  // Execute
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  // Close curl
  curl_close($ch);
  // Close file
  fclose($file);
}

// Download image
downloadImage('https://graph.facebook.com/WowSuchPage/picture?width=720&height=720');
```

The download succeeds though, but when I open the image file, it appears to be broken.
Here's the image that gets downloaded:

[image: Downloaded Image]

This only occurs when the image source is from Facebook, any other domains are OK. I don't think it has something to do with my ISP though because if I download the image through my browser, it's all fine

I hope you can help me on this one as this has been bugging me for some time now. Thanks!

**EDIT**

By the way, I'm using Wampserver 2.4 on localhost. My PHP version is 5.4.12

**FIXED**

Alright, I finally found the issue. It seems either cURL or the SSL component/extension in my local wampserver is the root of the issue. I only had to use "http://" rather than "https://" to access the image perfectly

But it would really be great if I can still download the image as perfect as it should be even in https://, I won't close this one yet until I find some answers. Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you using Facebook PHP SDK?

Comment: no.. the issue is, any photo I download from Facebook through the cript (not just from the Graph API), they always end up getting broken like the image above

Comment: even if you try to download this coca cola cover? try using this link instead of the graph api https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/t1/1979884_10153099001083306_1044481185_n.jpg

Comment: Yes, it's still broken.. the file size is OK though (I assume that's just natural 'cause of buffers)

Comment: @RonaldBorla did you try `$file = fopen($filename, 'wb');`??

Comment: try fetching the image with this curl settings `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
     curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);`

Comment: and also what @SabujHassan said

Comment: @SabujHassan Yes, I tried that as well, it still didn't work

Comment: @FabioAntunes Actually, I already tried that.. I even tried adding headers which regular browsers send, referred it using Firebug, and they still didn't work

Comment: I'm thinking it may have have something to do with a PHP setting, but I just don't know which one

Comment: Glad to see you fixed, but if it helps you, I used to use a curl function to get pictures from facebook, sometimes I got errors on the file because of the headers or something, then I discovered copy() and it solved all my problems: http://php.net/manual/es/function.copy.

Comment: @jesusbet I also tried that.. also file_get_contents(), still the same.. I still haven't figured this one out, it's definitely an issue with openssl. I'm guessing it's also an issue with the OS. I'm using Windows 7 64-bit